# how to insert and delete row data same time

Tags: php, mysql

hi this is my code for insert data into a database table and i want to delete data from one table and insert data in another table

```
<form action="page1.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="one" /> <br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>



</body>
</html>
<?php
include 'config.php';
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
$checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];
if ($_POST["submit"]=="submit")
{

$result = mysql_query("SELECT std_id,course_name,stdname FROM course_entry WHERE course_id = '".$checkbox1."' and username= '".$user."'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; echo $row[1]; 
echo $row[2];

$query= "INSERT INTO course_finish (course_id,course_name,username,finishdate) values ('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."','".$row[3]."',now())"; 
 "delete from course_entry where (course_id,username) values ('".$checkbox1."','".$user."'";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());


echo "Record is inserted";
header("Location: profile.php");    

}
?>
```

in database insert into course _finish is success full but in course_entry table the row isn't delete

Comment: Yook at the mysql documentatio for delete staments. Yours is purly wrong.

Comment: where have u written delete query

Comment: I recommend you use prepared statements instead of building the statements "by hand" (I mean, concatenating strings). Please read ["Bobby tables: A guide to prevent SQL injection"](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: see blow my complete solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO course_finish (course_id,course_name,username,finishdate) values ('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."','".$row[3]."',now())"; 
mysql_query($insertQuery) or die (mysql_error());

$deleteQuery = "DELETE from course_entry where course_id = '".$checkbox1."' AND username = '".$user."'";
mysql_query($deleteQuery ) or die (mysql_error());
```

Als note that the value of `$checkbox1` will be `one`. I don't know the type of `course_id` but if it's an `int` it won't succeed either.

Answer (score 0):

You delete query must look like:

```
delete from course_entry where course_id = ".$checkbox1." and username ='".$user."'
```

Second thing the mysql_* interface is deprecated. You schould use mysqli* or better pdo and prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= "INSERT INTO course_finish (course_id,course_name,username,finishdate) values ('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."','".$row[3]."',now())"; 
mysql_query("delete from course_entry where course_id='".$checkbox1."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your delete statement from

```
delete from course_entry where (course_id,username) values ('".$checkbox1."','".$user."'"
```

to

```
delete from course_entry where course_id='".$checkbox1."' and user_name='".$user."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution

```
    <?php 

<form action="page1.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="one" /> <br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>



</body>
</html>
<?php
include 'config.php';
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
$checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];
if ($_POST["submit"]=="submit")
{

$result = mysql_query("SELECT std_id,course_name,stdname FROM course_entry WHERE course_id = '".$checkbox1."' and username= '".$user."'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; echo $row[1]; 
echo $row[2];

$query= "INSERT INTO course_finish (course_id,course_name,username,finishdate) values ('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."','".$row[3]."',now())"; 
$deletequry=mysql_query("delete from course_entry where course_id='".$checkbox1."'");
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

if($deletequry){
    echo "deleted";
}

echo "Record is inserted";
header("Location: profile.php");    

}
?>
```

Comment: Now he still doesn't know if hiss delete query is successed or not.

Comment: he has not written delet query at all

Comment: if(mysql_query("delete from course_entry where course_id='".$checkbox1."'")){

Comment: True, that's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that none of the other answers covers **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**! This is pretty important here since you take user input which *can* be dangerous because of [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Here is my recommended way to do it (OOP style):

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
$db->set_charset('utf8');

$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT std_id,course_name,stdname FROM course_entry WHERE course_id = ? and username = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt1->bind_param('is', $checkbox1, $user);
$stmt1->execute();
$result1 = $stmt1->get_result();
$stmt1->close();
$row = $result1->fetch_row();
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO course_finish (course_id,course_name,username,finishdate) values (?, ?, ?, NOW())");
$stmt2->bind_param('iss', $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]); //i think it's $row[2], not $row[3]
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->close();
$stmt3 = $db->prepare("delete from course_entry where (course_id, username) values (?, ?)");
$stmt3->bind_param('is', $checkbox1, $user);
$stmt3->execute();
$stmt3->close();
$db->close();
```

Maybe you don't like the code (I don't, too, but because I don't like mysqli haha), but it is really advisable to use prepared statements where you can.

Hope this helps.